# How to reach an HTTPS site via proxy with Hyper?

Tags: rust, http-proxy, hyper

The following is an attempt to reach an HTTPS site via proxy:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_native_tls;

use hyper::net::HttpsConnector;
use hyper::client::{Client, ProxyConfig};
use hyper_native_tls::NativeTlsClient;

fn main() {
    let ssl = NativeTlsClient::new().unwrap();
    let connector = HttpsConnector::new(ssl);

    let client = Client::with_proxy_config(
        ProxyConfig::new(
            "http", "localhost", 3128, connector, ssl
        )
    );

    let response = client.get("https://httpbin.org").send().unwrap();
    println!("{}", response.headers);
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         ProxyConfig::new(
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>`
   |
   = note: `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>` cannot be formatted using `:?`; if it is defined in your crate, add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement it
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `hyper::net::SslClient<hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>>` for `hyper_native_tls::NativeTlsClient`
   = note: required by `<hyper::client::ProxyConfig<C, S>>::new`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |           ProxyConfig::new(
   |  _________^ starting here...
14 | |             "http", "localhost", 3128, connector, ssl
15 | |         )
   | |_________^ ...ending here: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>`
   |
   = note: `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>` cannot be formatted using `:?`; if it is defined in your crate, add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement it
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `hyper::net::SslClient<hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>>` for `hyper_native_tls::NativeTlsClient`
   = note: required by `hyper::client::ProxyConfig`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |     let client = Client::with_proxy_config(
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>`
   |
   = note: `hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>` cannot be formatted using `:?`; if it is defined in your crate, add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement it
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `hyper::net::SslClient<hyper::net::HttpsStream<hyper_native_tls::TlsStream<hyper::net::HttpStream>>>` for `hyper_native_tls::NativeTlsClient`
   = note: required by `hyper::Client::with_proxy_config`
```

Here are the Cargo dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.10"
hyper-native-tls = "0.2"
```

Things are better using these dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.10"
hyper-openssl = "0.2"
```

And this code:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_openssl;

use hyper::net::HttpsConnector;
use hyper::client::{Client, ProxyConfig};
use hyper_openssl::OpensslClient as TlsClient;

fn main() {
    let ssl = TlsClient::new().unwrap();
    let connector = HttpsConnector::new(ssl.clone());

    let client = Client::with_proxy_config(
        ProxyConfig::new(
            "http", "localhost", 3128, connector, ssl
        )
    );

    let response = client.get("https://httpbin.org").send().unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", response);
}
```

Output:

```
Response {
    status: Ok,
    headers: Headers { Server: nginx, Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:05:13 GMT, Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 12150, Connection: keep-alive, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, },
    version: Http11,
    url: "https://httpbin.org/",
    status_raw: RawStatus(
        200,
        "OK"
    ),
    message: Http11Message {
        is_proxied: false,
        method: None,
        stream: Wrapper {
            obj: Some(
                Reading(
                    SizedReader(remaining=12150)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

No build failures there, but it doesn't go via the proxy.

Comment: Aren't all these errors caused by the fact you are trying to print the `response` in debug mode while it doesn't implement `Debug`?

Comment: I get the same error even if I don't print anything

Comment: None of the structures on [`hyper_native_tls`](https://docs.rs/hyper-native-tls/0.2.0/hyper_native_tls/) seem to impl `Debug`, so the behaviour seen on that code would be correct. Please make sure that you are not performing any `fmt()` and update the question with your findings.

Comment: @E_net4: Should probably be an answer. I checked [`ProxyConfig`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.0/hyper/client/struct.ProxyConfig.html) and [`Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.0/hyper/client/struct.Client.html#method.with_proxy_config) and neither require `Debug`, so it seems the OP is shooting himself in the foot... and that the error message isn't great. Or maybe he's not using the latest version of hyper (0.10.0) and thus the docs I'm consulting are not good.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In a way, that is true. On the other hand, the question is of poor quality and doesn't refer at all to the use of `Debug`-formatted output in its phrasing. I'd rather let it either be improved or deleted. I also wonder whether there's a suitable duplicate.

Comment: I've updated the Question @E_net4

Comment: And the error still states "cannot be formatted using `:?`"?

Comment: @ljedrz yeah, same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some untested conflicts around the crates `hyper_native_tls` and `native_tls`.

Currently, there is a restriction on the implementation of `SslClient` for `NativeTlsClient` that requires `T: Debug` ([code](https://github.com/sfackler/hyper-native-tls/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L122)). The code in the question does not compile because `TlsStream` does not implement Debug, regardless of its parameter type.

At first one could consider removing the aforementioned constraint. But that triggers a few other errors in `hyper_native_tls`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:129:45
    |
129 |             Err(e) => Err(hyper::Error::Ssl(Box::new(e))),
    |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `T`
    |
    = help: consider adding a `where T: std::fmt::Debug` bound
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `native_tls::HandshakeError<T>`
    = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::error::Error + std::marker::Sync + std::marker::Send + 'static`
```

Going down the rabbit hole, we discover that [`native_tls::HandshakeError`](https://docs.rs/native-tls/0.1.1/native_tls/enum.HandshakeError.html) holds a parameter type `S` of the stream that was interrupted (in case of this particular error). This became another problem because the type only implements `Debug` where `S: Debug`, and according to the [Error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait, error types must always implement `Debug`.

A fix to this particular issue is to provide `Debug` to `TlsStream`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct TlsStream<S>(Arc<Mutex<native_tls::TlsStream<S>>>);
```

The first code snippet still won't compile because `ssl` is being used after moving, and copying is not tolerated here. The second snippet works by cloning the object, which is unfortunately not implemented for `NativeTlsClient`. We also cannot derive the implementation because `native_tls::TlsConnector` does not implement `Clone` either. As far as this rabbit hole went, it should probably end here before this becomes a debugging report.

I am not entirely sure of what can be done here (aside from not using native TLS at all), but my current advice would be filing an issue in `hyper_native_tls_client`, explaining that it doesn't work with hyper's client proxy (edit: [it's done and fixed!](https://github.com/sfackler/hyper-native-tls/issues/1)).

Comment: https://github.com/sfackler/hyper-native-tls/commit/30e9d1574774aa9267ca8d4770f9af21f04edb13

Comment: @Tshepang Good job. ;)