# Hyper says "Invalid scheme for Http" for HTTPS URLs

Tags: ssl, https, rust, hyper

I have

```
hyper = "0.10"
```

And the following code:

```
let client = Client::new();
let mut res = client.get("https://google.com").send().unwrap();
```

Rust gives me the error message, as if it doesn't have SSL support:

> Invalid scheme for Http

This is on Rust 1.14.0 on Debian jessie.

How do I get Hyper to connect with SSL to an HTTPS URL?

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614923/how-to-reach-an-https-site-via-proxy) that uses the new `hyper-native-tls` crate.

Comment: For hyper 0.11, the answer is in the documentation under 'Client Configuration': https://hyper.rs/guides/client/configuration/ .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_native_tls;

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::net::HttpsConnector;
use hyper_native_tls::NativeTlsClient;

fn main() {
    let ssl = NativeTlsClient::new().unwrap();
    let connector = HttpsConnector::new(ssl);
    let client = Client::with_connector(connector);
    let mut res = client.get("https://google.com").send().unwrap();
}
```

Mostly taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614923/how-to-reach-an-https-site-via-proxy). What was missing was the `Client::with_connector` piece.

Comment: Interesting, so `hyper` ensure that you have a TLS-capable client before allowing the `https` scheme. That's neat!

Comment: @MatthieuM. I believe that was a recent change as TLS related code got put into the other crate. This code is using hyper 0.10.